# Do facebook & twitter have 'union id' like QQ & WeChat for identification across apps?

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, twitter-login

When we login in our apps with a QQ or WeChat account, QQ and WeChat provide an `union id` to tell us we use the same QQ or WeChat account, so we can synchronize data between different apps.
So do Facebook & twitter have union id or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Google has `sub` returned by their `/oauth2/v3/userinfo` resource, and Facebook has `id` returned by their `/v2.8/{userid}` resource. These values are not unique for a single application, they are the user's unique identifier. You can use these ids to synchronize data.